# How to display variables in cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to get a table view to display data from an array.

The error says

> Use of Unidentifiable identifier tableItems

Here is the implementation file of the tvc:

```
@interface IDTVC ()
@property NSMutableArray *tableItems;

@end

@implementation IDTVC
-(void)loadInitialData {
    IDModel *item1 = [[IDModel alloc] init];
    item1.name = @"Hamburger";
    item1.sub = @"test";
    //identify image here
    item1.pic =@"pic.png";
    [self.tableItems addObject:item1];
    IDModel *item2 = [[IDModel alloc] init];
    item2.name = @"Cheeseburger";
    item2.sub = @"test";
    item2.pic =@"pic.png";
    [self.tableItems addObject:item2];
    IDModel *item3 = [[IDModel alloc] init];
    item3.name = @"Hot Dog";
    item3.sub = @"test";
    item3.pic =@"pic.png";
    [self.tableItems addObject:item3];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self loadInitialData];
 }

static NSString *protoCell = @"Cell";
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:protoCell forIndexPath:indexPath];
// Configure the cell...

//RED ERROR IN FOLLOWING LINE
    cell.textLabel.text = [tableItems.name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
    //    cell.textLabel.text = @"head";
      cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"sub";

    return cell;
}
```

What is appropriate syntax to grab name in `tableItems` array and assign it to `labelText`?

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a subclass 'MyCustomCell' for UITableViewCell and add you properties there.

in your .h file

```
@interface MyCustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *myTitle;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *detailTitle;

@end
```

in your .m file

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {

        _myTitle = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        _detailTitle = [[UILabel alloc] init];

        [self.contentView addSubview:_myTitle];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_detailTitle];

    }

    return self;
}
```

in your UITableViewController add your import your custom subclass

Create NSString properties for your name and sub in your UITableViewController

```
#import "MyCustomCell"
```

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *requestCell = @"myCell";

    MyCustomCell *cell;


    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:requestCell forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.myTitle.frame = CGRectMake(105, 0, self.view.frame.size.width - 155, 50);
    cell.detailTitle.frame = CGRectMake(105, 50, self.view.frame.size.width - 110, 15);

    cell.myTitle.text = _tableItems.name;
    cell.detailTitle.text = _tableItems.sub;  

    return cell;
}
```

***NOT TESTED

Comment: Worked.  So much for people's up and down votes.  Guy who provided first answer when I questioned him removed his answer and down voted my question and your answer vinylDeveloper but your answer is correct!  I can only up vote once.  Thanks!

Comment: I am using dequeue.  What method would this go in?  Also, can I use same syntax in prepare for segue?

Comment: this answer is faulty. it creates an unneeded object.

Comment: what is `_myArray` supposed to be if it has properties `name` and `sub`?

Comment: the name doesn't make a difference.an array doesn't have a property name or sub.

Comment: I told him to create properties for those, accidentally erased them when I edited, added it again

Comment: again: NSArray has no property name or sub. and it would male no sense to add those.

Comment: and why should it get them by declaring it in the view controller? what about the model?

Comment: IDModel in above does not sub class uicell but rather nsobject and contains properties.  I deleted the alloc init from your original answer and it still works fine. I just have IDModel * model;

Answer (score 1):

It should be `_tableItems` or `self.tableItems`. You are using it correct in other methods, but not in `UITableView` delegate method. Also if `ARC` is enabled, make `tableItems` property `strong` as:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *tableItems;
```

Comment: with both self.tableItems and _tableItems get Property name not found on object of type 'NSMutableArray' error.

Comment: given to the codes OP added in the question, this is the correct answer. sadly OP tries to access a NSMutableArray as if it was another object.